# How to find culprit class/object by looking at memory profiler result in visualVM

Tags: java, profiling, profiler, visualvm

I am profiling my Java application using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)
and I have gone through

[profiling_with_visualvm_part_1](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_1)

[profiling_with_visualvm_part_2](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_2)

When I see memory profile result, I see millions of `Objects[]`, `Char[]`, `String` and other such fundamental objects created which is taking all the memory. **I want to know which of my classes (or my code) are actually responsible for creating those** `Objects[]` and `String` etc, so far I couldn't find it. Once I know the culprit class I can dive-in the code and fix it.

I put a filter `com.mypackage.*`, but I see all of them are many times smaller (sometimes 0byte) compared to the total size of `Objects[]`,`Char[]`, `String` objects.

I believe, there should be a way to find the culprit code. Otherwise, profiler won't be of much use.

Let me know if my question is not clear, I will try to clarify further.

Comment: Not a answer to my question but, I found a helpful link to find memory leak, it involves some intuition http://rejeev.blogspot.com/2009/04/analyzing-memory-leak-in-java.html Since, I am not specifically looking for memory leak, so this link is not answering my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see, which code allocates those instances, go to 'Memory settings' and enable 'Record allocations stack traces'. 'Record allocations stack traces' option is explained ['Profiling with VisualVM part 2'](https://web.archive.org/web/20090210024746/http://blogs.sun.com:80/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_2). Once you turned it on, profile your application, take snapshot of profiling results. In the snapshot right-click on the particular class and invoke 'Show allocation stacktraces'.

Comment: Thanks! I already did that. Isn't the same thing in bullet 5 of article I posted http://rejeev.blogspot.com/2009/04/analyzing-memory-leak-in-java.html. Won't it be little un-practical to go through all the instances one by one (let me know if I am missing something). I was looking for a way to see details of my own classes with how many instances of different fundamental objects they are creating. Maybe something like `myClassA=700mb` and when I drill down I can see different objects making up that 700mb. Feel free to suggest any other profiler which can do the same if VisualVM cannot.

Comment: I am confused. There are no individual instances in allocation backtraces view. Allocations of once class are grouped by their stacktraces. So if particular method in your class allocates String object, you will see it at the first level of allocation stacktraces view and you will also see on the right side how many instances were allocated by your method. I think this is exactly what you want - at least this is how I understand your question.

Comment: Can you provide better instructions? I still find visualvm information useless... How can I know who is creating tons of char objects? http://i.imgur.com/Gdp8xgf.png

Comment: Please read 'Profiling with VisualVM part 2'. I just updated the link to the blog post. It describes how to access "Memory settings".